# How to checked check box in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

- I have two list (List 1 and List 2) of check box in which three items
  available in both list. My problem is when I checked on list 1 item
  then list 2 item also checked not sure why. I need to stop this. My
  requirement is when I checked list 1 item then it does not affect
  List 2 item. Please help

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t7kr8/679/)

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="checkbox" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in list">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"  
             ng-click="fnChangeAssetType1(item)" />
        <label>{{item.value}}</label>
    </div>
    <br/><br/>
    New List<br/><br/>
    <div ng-repeat="items in lists">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="items.checked"  
             ng-click="fnChangeAssetType(items)"  />
        <label>{{items.value}}</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('checkbox', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
       var list = [{
            "id": 1,
            "value": "apple",
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "value": "orange",
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "value": "pear"
        }];

     $scope.list=list;
     $scope.lists=list;

    $scope.fnChangeAssetType = function (items) {
        angular.forEach($scope.lists, function (item) {
            item.checked = false;
        });
        items.checked = true;
    };
    $scope.fnChangeAssetType1 = function (items) {
        angular.forEach($scope.list, function (item) {
            item.checked = false;
        });
        items.checked = true;
    };

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `$scope.list` & `$scope.lists` both are pointing to same array in the memory because of array (`list`) is a reference type. what u need to do is create a separate array for `$scope.lists` as below.

you need to use [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.list=list;
$scope.lists= angular.copy(list); // this will create a deep copy of list array and store it in another memory slot, //refer the angular.copy doc
```

here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zpr2ox7y/)

Comment: @K. Toress:- Really appreciate this. Working smoothly.

Comment: it's glad to help you here :)